# how to rotate a fragment inside an activity without activity rotation?

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, fragment, orientation

There is an android program
I have a bottom navigation bar inside my app that i don't want to change its orientation because of quality reduce 
I want to rotate a fragment inside an activity when change orientation of the phone without activity rotation. how can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

Open your Manifest.XML
Find your activity.
Add tag inside

```
<activity
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```